# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date when trying to convert "2013-07-01T04:37:14.771468Z" into Local time

Tags: java, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I need to convert UTC time string I get into local time using following method,

```
String dateCreate = "2013-07-01T04:37:14.771468Z"

DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'Z'");
dfParse.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"));
java.util.Date dateTime;
dateTime = dfParse.parse(dateCreate);
String dteCreate = df.format(dateTime);
```

Can someone plese give me a solution for this.? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is xsd dateTime format. You should use javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter for that

```
Calendar c = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(lexicalXSDDateTime);
```

Note that for SmipleDateFormat `S` means number of milliseconds so it will parse 771468 as 771468 ms not 0.771468 sec which adds extra 771 secs to the result date

Formatting part is OK

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Now that I've checked it supports this easily, I'd strongly recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). Its ISO-8601 parser works fine:

```
String dateCreate = "2013-07-01T04:37:14.771468Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime parsed = formatter.parseDateTime(dateCreate);
```

By default that will convert to the system default time zone, but you can change that behaviour with calls on `DateTimeFormatter`.

Joda Time is also a *much* cleaner API than the built-in one - you'll find any date/time code is easier to write and easier to read.

---

Look at your input data and your pattern:

```
String dateCreate = "2013-07-01T04:37:14.771468Z";

DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

They don't match at all. You need **something like**:

```
// Don't use this directly!
DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
dfParse.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Or:

```
// Don't use this directly!
DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX");
```

The latter will cope with any ISO-8601 time zone; the former restricts to UTC.

Unfortunately, the above will end up with the wrong number of milliseconds as it will take *all* the microseconds to be milliseconds. I don't know of a way of avoiding this in Java... you *may* need to trim the string first. For example:

```
// Remove the sub-millisecond part, assuming it's three digits:
int firstPartLength = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS".length();
String noMicros = dateCreate.substring(0, firstPartLength) +
                  dateCreate.substring(firstPartLength + 3);
// Now we've got text without micros, so create an appropriate pattern
DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
Date date = dfParse.parse(noMicros);
```

Alternatively, if you know it's always going to end with "Z":

```
int firstPartLength = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS".length();
String noMicros = dateCreate.substring(0, firstPartLength);
DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
dfParse.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = dfParse.parse(noMicros);
```

This is irritating, and it would be nice to be able to tell Java to treat any digits after the dot as "fractions of a second" but I don't *know* of any way of doing that using `SimpleDateFormat`. Note that you wouldn't be able to represent the sub-millisecond value using just `Date` anyway.

Comment: my time string not always giving exact same no of digits in micro seconds section. so is there a way to match it with any no of digits.? :)

Comment: @Sajirupee: No, not easily. You'll basically need to use string manipulation, I suspect :( If you can provide more information in the question, we may be able to help you more. Tell us everything you can about your input data. Does is always end in `Z` for example?

Comment: @Sajirupee: See my alternative suggestion - use Joda Time instead. (I've edited the start of the answer.)

Comment: found a solution from @Evgeniy Dorofeev answer. thanx for the help :)

Comment: @Sajirupee: I would still strongly urge you to use Joda Time if you possibly can.

Comment: I will also look into that too. but for now this solution is work for me. thank you :)